# Asterisk Sip Server and "Screen Sharing" function

Tags: asterisk, voip, sip

I'am newbie in asterisk, i followed the tutorials on the asterisk wiki, and installed the latest version (13) of the asterisk server. I was able to setup the voip now i wonder, there is a function im my SIP client - "screen sharing". Is it require the same modules as the video conference? I have all the codecs installed on the system and on my server and i have the "app_confbridge" module. How do i configure the screen sharing? Currently i have

```
[general]
videosupport=yes

[someone]
allow=h263,h264
```

But when i click "share screen" on my BLINK sip softphone, it starts the audio call. Is there some specific extension required to share screen?

Comment: Screen sharing is video; it may ask for better quality codecs though. Does standard video calling work ?

Comment: @AndréDaniel it wasn't working with asterisk. I switched to Opensips, and i did setup the MSRP RELAY. It allowed me to do screen sharing and other nice functions. I gueess i will close the question. Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, by switching to opensips server and using the MSRPRELAY along with it. It's a standalone module, which can be used with opensips, you simple install MSRPRELAY, edit the config.ini to make sure it connects with opensips user table, and it's working! In the blink you have to specify MSRPRELAY address in the "server settings" tab.